# QT always on top on windows7/8

Tags: c++, windows, qt, window

I would like to know if it's possible to set my QMainWindow always on top .

I tried:

```
mainWindow.setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnBottomHint);
```

mainWindow is a QMainWindow extended object. 
But it doesn't work and my window disapear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but there are two errors in your code:

1. You are clearing all flags but `Qt::WindowStaysOnBottomHint` which is set.
2. You're using `Qt::WindowStaysOnBottomHint` flag (which represent the opposite of what you want) instead of `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint`.

A correct way of doing that is:

```
Qt::WindowFlags flags = mainWindow.windowFlags();
mainWindow.setWindowFlags(flags | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
```

> Note that on some window managers on X11 you also have to pass
>   Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint for this flag to work correctly.

In that case you should do:

```
Qt::WindowFlags flags = mainWindow.windowFlags();
mainWindow.setWindowFlags(flags | Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
```

Comment: Oops, my bad. I copied the wrong flag when posting my question. I tried Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint which was not working. Your answer did what i expected. Thanks for the answer with X11 recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a window as Dialog, there is another way. Just call setModal(true) or setWindowModality(), afterward show(). Unlike exec(), show() returns control to the caller instantaneously.It wont stuck as QDialog in exec().

i.e

```
setModel(true);//In Constructor
```

then while calling or invoking the new window,

```
MyWindow* myWindow = new MyWindow(this);
myWindow->show();
```